# Using ON DELETE both ways, with a 1-1 relationship, where only table has a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Assume I have two tables, `a` and `b`. Table `a` contains an optional `FOREIGN KEY` reference to `b`. Table `b` *does not* have a `FOREIGN KEY` reference to table `a`, and should not. The reason for this is that table `a` is not the only table that might reference a row from table `b`: tables `x` and `y` might also reference `b`, and more tables might be added in the future which might reference a row from `b`.

So, every row from table `b` has exactly one "owner row" which may belong to `a`, `x`, `y`, or potentially any one of a number of other tables.

Now, if a row from table `b` is deleted, I want it to set the foreign key reference to itself from `a`, `x`, or `y`, if there is one, to null. I know I can accomplish this using `ON DELETE SET NULL` in the foreign key constraints for `a` and the other tables, so that is taken care of.

However, if the "owner row" is deleted, regardless of whether that row lives in `a`, `x`, `y`, or whatever, I want the corresponding row from `b` to be deleted as well. This is what I'm not sure how to do.

In short:

1. `a` references `b`. This is an optional reference, not all `a`s will have a `b`.

   - (`x`, `y`, and other tables also have similar relationships to `b`)
2. `b` does not and should not reference `a` or any of those other tables.
3. If I delete from `a` and if the given `a` has a corresponding `b`, that `b` should be deleted.
4. If I delete from `b`, and any other table contains a reference to that `b`, the reference should be set to null.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table a
( ...
, b_id  bigint default null comment 'fk ref b.id'
, constraint a_b_id foreign key (b_id) reference b (id) on delete set null 
, ...
) engine=innodb
```

tables `x` and `y` are defined similarly, with nullable foreign key columns

```
create table x 
( ...
, b_id  bigint default null comment 'fk ref b.id'
, constraint x_b_id foreign key (b_id) references b (id) on delete set null 
, ...
) engine=innodb
```

and

```
create table y 
( ...
, b_id  bigint default null comment 'fk ref b.id'
, constraint y_b_id foreign key (b_id) references b (id) on delete set null 
, ...
) engine=innodb
```

---

When a row is deleted from `b`, then any values of `b_id` column in any of the three tables references the deleted row, those values will be change to NULL.

---

There is no declarative constraint in MySQL that will accomplish 3.

"If I delete from a and if the given a has a corresponding b, that b should be deleted."

We might be able to accomplish this with a TRIGGER, but we get into some issues with which tables can be referenced by statements in the trigger. This would probably better be handled with the application logic, rather than a database rule or trigger.

If I was going to attempt a trigger, then something like

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE TRIGGER a_ad
 AFTER DELETE ON a
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    DELETE FROM b WHERE b.id = OLD.b_id ;
 END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

(I'm not sure that this will be allowed, or if an error is going to be thrown...  consider

```
table b
---------
row id=42
```

and

```
table a
-------
row id=2  b_id=42
row id=3  b_id=42
```

consider this SQL statement

```
DELETE FROM a WHERE a.id IN (2,3);
```

The delete of row `id=2` is going to fire the "after delete" trigger; and that will perform a DELETE on `b`, the foreign key will find the row `id=3` referencing, and attempt to set the `b_id` column to NULL... but that row might already be locked by the initial DELETE statement... I'm just not sure what will happen in this scenario; and we run into some limitations and restrictions on triggers (like against modifying rows in tables that are referenced in the statement that fires the trigger, )

Comment: The `ON DELETE` statement makes sense of course. Triggers are kind of black magic to me right now, but I'll play with that and see if it works. Thank you.